# Find the most recent date two file lists have in common

Tags: find, regular-expression, backup, date

### Problem

I would like to modify my [backup script](https://gist.github.com/calebreister/3d04aa3c81affd4d43ec) so that it automatically determines the correct date for the most recent backup. Currently, it just outputs the list of files on my internal and external drive, and I enter a date manually.

Here is what a typical session would look like. My input is in quotes.

```
$ sudo backup.sh
/dev/mapper/cr-root:
@             @-2016-07-27      @home-2016-06-24  @home-2016-08-01
@-2016-06-19  @-2016-07-29      @home-2016-06-27  @home-2016-08-04
@-2016-06-24  @-2016-08-01      @home-2016-07-06  @home-2016-08-07
@-2016-06-27  @-2016-08-04      @home-2016-07-09  @home-2016-08-13
@-2016-07-06  @-2016-08-07      @home-2016-07-11  @music
@-2016-07-09  @-2016-08-13      @home-2016-07-15  @music-2016-06-27
@-2016-07-11  @-2016-08-19      @home-2016-07-22  @music-2016-07-06
@-2016-07-15  @-clean           @home-2016-07-24  @music-2016-07-09
@-2016-07-22  @home             @home-2016-07-27
@-2016-07-24  @home-2016-06-19  @home-2016-07-29
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sdb1:
@-2015-10-17  @-2016-07-27         @home-2015-12-30
@-2015-10-24  @-2016-07-29         @home-2016-01-01
@-2015-10-30  @-2016-08-01         @home-2016-01-03
@-2015-11-10  @-2016-08-04         @home-2016-01-07
@-2015-11-11  @-2016-08-07         @home-2016-01-10
@-2015-11-12  @-2016-08-13         @home-2016-01-12
@-2015-11-20  @-2016-08-19         @home-2016-01-14
@-2015-11-21  @-clean              @home-2016-01-21
@-2015-11-25  @Dropbox-2015-10-17  @home-2016-01-26
@-2015-12-01  @Dropbox-2015-10-24  @home-2016-01-28
@-2015-12-10  @Dropbox-2015-10-30  @home-2016-02-13
@-2015-12-14  @Dropbox-2015-11-10  @home-2016-02-15
@-2015-12-15  @Dropbox-2015-11-20  @home-2016-02-17
@-2015-12-19  @Dropbox-2015-11-25  @home-2016-02-18
@-2015-12-20  @Dropbox-2015-12-01  @home-2016-02-26
@-2015-12-30  @Dropbox-2015-12-10  @home-2016-03-01
@-2016-01-01  @Dropbox-2015-12-14  @home-2016-03-04
@-2016-01-03  @Dropbox-2015-12-19  @home-2016-03-07
@-2016-01-07  @Dropbox-2015-12-20  @home-2016-03-12
@-2016-01-10  @Dropbox-2015-12-30  @home-2016-03-18
@-2016-01-12  @Dropbox-2016-01-01  @home-2016-03-28
@-2016-01-14  @Dropbox-2016-01-03  @home-2016-03-29
@-2016-01-21  @Dropbox-2016-01-07  @home-2016-04-05
@-2016-01-26  @Dropbox-2016-01-10  @home-2016-04-06
@-2016-01-28  @Dropbox-2016-01-12  @home-2016-04-09
@-2016-02-04  @Dropbox-2016-01-14  @home-2016-04-15
@-2016-02-05  @Dropbox-2016-01-21  @home-2016-04-18
@-2016-02-06  @Dropbox-2016-01-26  @home-2016-04-22
@-2016-02-13  @Dropbox-2016-01-28  @home-2016-05-01
@-2016-02-15  @Dropbox-2016-02-04  @home-2016-05-06
@-2016-02-17  @Dropbox-2016-02-05  @home-2016-05-08
@-2016-02-18  @Dropbox-2016-02-06  @home-2016-05-24
@-2016-02-26  @Dropbox-2016-02-13  @home-2016-06-04
@-2016-03-01  @Dropbox-2016-02-15  @home-2016-06-08
@-2016-03-04  @Dropbox-2016-02-17  @home-2016-06-14
@-2016-03-07  @Dropbox-2016-02-18  @home-2016-06-17
@-2016-03-12  @Dropbox-2016-02-26  @home-2016-06-19
@-2016-03-18  @Dropbox-2016-03-01  @home-2016-06-24
@-2016-03-28  @Dropbox-2016-03-04  @home-2016-06-27
@-2016-03-29  @Dropbox-2016-03-07  @home-2016-07-06
@-2016-04-05  @Dropbox-2016-03-12  @home-2016-07-09
@-2016-04-06  @Dropbox-2016-03-18  @home-2016-07-11
@-2016-04-09  @Dropbox-2016-03-28  @home-2016-07-15
@-2016-04-15  @Dropbox-2016-03-29  @home-2016-07-22
@-2016-04-18  @Dropbox-2016-04-05  @home-2016-07-24
@-2016-04-22  @Dropbox-2016-04-06  @home-2016-07-27
@-2016-05-01  @Dropbox-2016-04-09  @home-2016-07-29
@-2016-05-06  @Dropbox-2016-04-15  @home-2016-08-01
@-2016-05-08  @Dropbox-2016-04-18  @home-2016-08-04
@-2016-05-24  @Dropbox-2016-04-22  @home-2016-08-07
@-2016-06-04  @home-2015-10-17     @home-2016-08-13
@-2016-06-08  @home-2015-10-24
@-2016-06-14  @home-2015-11-10
@-2016-06-17  @home-2015-11-11
@-2016-06-19  @home-2015-11-12
@-2016-06-24  @home-2015-11-20
@-2016-06-27  @home-2015-11-21
@-2016-07-06  @home-2015-11-25
@-2016-07-09  @home-2015-12-01
@-2016-07-11  @home-2015-12-10
@-2016-07-15  @home-2015-12-14
@-2016-07-22  @home-2015-12-19
@-2016-07-24  @home-2015-12-20
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Backup @ [y/n]? "y"
Backup @home [y/n]? "y"
Backup @music [y/n]? "n"
Date of previous version: "2016-08-13"
...
```

For a given subvolume (such as `@` or `@home`), I want to find the most recent dated snapshot that both have in common. In this case, I am looking for `@-2016-08-13` and `@home-2016-08-13`, respectively. I am able to use `find` to output all of the files of the form `@-date`, for example, but I then need to compare the dates and find the most recent that both lists have. I know that a regex alone probably can't do this, but I'm not sure what will.

### TL;DR

I want to find the most recent common date in a list of files without using timestamps. For instance, given these lists...

```
@-2016-07-24 @-2016-08-01 @-2016-08-13 @-2016-08-19
```

and

```
@-2016-07-24 @-2016-08-01 @-2016-08-13
```

I want to find the common file with the highest date, which is `@-2016-08-13` in this case. I would prefer to use built-in UNIX utilities to do this.

Comment: Maybe `join` the `sort`ed lists and `tail` the result? Probably needs your `sort` to have a `-V` (natural version) sort. The exact implementation will depend what you mean by a "list" (string? shell array? file?).

Comment: @steeldriver By list I just mean `ls` output. It can be in the `ls -1` form or space-delimited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find `@home` and `@` recent date

```
comm -12 <(grep -oP '@home-\K[0-9-]*' bkup.list | sort) \
         <(grep -oP '@-\K[0-9-]*' bkup.list | sort) |
tail -n 1
```

Comment: It works. I can modify it from there.